# Using Kotlin how can a base class operate on a list of base class objects, from its derived class which has a list of derived class objects?

Tags: list, kotlin, inheritance, covariance, declare

I have a setup vaguely like below (sorry if the Kotlin/pseudo syntax is just confusing, let me know and I'll change it).
I've got two derived classes that hold lists whose items are derived class instances. Where the list base classes have generic functionality for the lists.
I was just wondering if the way I'm doing this is silly. Is there a better way to use the derived class lists (List, List) in the base class than adding another property for the list (List) and updating it in the derived class each time changes are made to the list?
I kind of want to declare the 'items' list property in the base class A, and then override with a derived type in B and C. With the methods in class A using the list cast to the generic base class (List). But you can't do that.
Cheers, hope this is of interest to someone.

```
class A {
    val genericItems = List<a>

    methodForGenericItems() {
        do something generic with/to the list
    }
}

class B : A {
    val items = List<b>

    updateItems() {
        update items
        genericItems = items as List<a>
    }

    methodForDerivedItems() {
        do something specific using the list
        call methodForGenericItems()
    }
}

class C : A {
    val items = List<c>

    updateItems() {
        update items
        genericItems = items as List<a>
    }

    methodForDerivedItems() {
        do something specific using the list
        call methodForGenericItems()
    }
}

class a {
    ...
}

class b : a {
    ...
}

class c : a {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is a shame you didn't try to rewrite your pseudo-code to Kotlin, because then you would discover you can achieve this with exactly your code :-) Why do you think this is not possible?

Comment: Also, do you need to ever modify the list of items in the `A` directly or only in derived classes? In latter case, you can really use only one property, without any synchronization.

Comment: Haha yer I did it like this, just felt like there might be a better way to do it! Seemed a bit weird to have an additional property that is the same as another just cast to its base class and that you need to update whenever you change the original

Comment: There is at least one method in A that modifies the list. Removes at a certain index. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on whether we need to add new items in the base class (`A`) or not. If we need to do this then we have a problem, because `A` doesn't know about additional restrictions on item types introduced by `B` and `C`. Therefore, what if we use `B` class which works with `b` items, but one of functions of `A` adds an item of `c` type? We would have a list of `b` items, but containing `c` which breaks type safety. There are some solutions to this problem, depending on specific needs.

In your case it seems you only need to read/remove items in `A`. This is much simpler and does not require any workarounds. It is sufficient to have a regular, single property and just override its type in the subclass. But we need to inform the compiler that we won't ever add new items in `A`. We can do it like this:

```
open class A {
    open val items: MutableList<out a> = mutableListOf()
}

class B : A() {
    override val items = mutableListOf<b>()
}
```

`out a` in this code means that `A` can only "pull" `a` objects from `items`, but it can't "push" `a` objects to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot this seems like exactly what I needed. Pointed me towards this article https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-type-variance-in-kotlin-d12ad566241b in case anyone else wants further info